# junit : get method of CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> never return

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, completable-future

In my Spring boot application, I have below two methods,
I am writing JUnit for method1 and mocking method **processQuery()**. but I don't know why when the control reaches to **result.get()** , It got stuck, and not moving further.

```
Method 1:
public class Entry(){
public string method1(){
   --some process and then calling method 2
 CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = 
 risk.processQuery(graphQLRequest, context);
 **result.get();** **--Control got stuck here** 
 system.out.println("control not reaching here ");
 }
}

  **TestClass ::**

public class testMain(){
  @InjectMock
  Entry entry;
  @Mock
  Risk risk;

 @Before
    public void setup() {
    entry= new Entry();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

 @Test
   public void testMethod1(){
     CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = new 
     CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>();


Mockito.doReturn(result).when(risk).processQuery(Mockitt.anyString(),Mockito.any());

entry.method1();
}
```

Kinde helps me with the above issue.

Comment: you don't call your method1. what did you expect to happen? also: why do you do an inject of your Entry class?

Comment: You are waiting for your `CompleteableFuture` to complete using `get`. If it never returns the logical consequence is that it never completes. You might want to check that.

Comment: Hi @Stultuske updated the code, sorry I missed the method call.

Comment: Hhi @Ben , I am mocking the whole call , So how can i check for logical consequence , kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You are mocking `risk.processQuery()` with an uncompleted `CompletableFuture`

```
CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = new CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>();
Mockito.doReturn(result).when(risk).processQuery(Mockitt.anyString(),Mockito.any());
```

When you call `get()` on a `CompletableFuture`, it waits until it is completed with a value or an exception. Here you future is never completed, so it waits indefinitely.

You have three solutions here:

- define your mock such that it returns an already completed future:

  ```
  CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(someResult);
  ```
- make the test call `entry.method1()` in a separate thread (e.g. with `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`) and then complete the result with `result.complete(someResult)` in the test;
- refactor your code such that `method1()` becomes asynchronous as well, something like:

  ```
  public CompletableFuture<String> method1(){
      --some process and then calling method 2
      CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = 
      risk.processQuery(graphQLRequest, context);
      return result.thenApply(result -> result.toString());
  }
  ```

  then adapt your test to mimic an asynchronous response:

  ```
  @Test
  public void testMethod1(){
      CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult> result = new CompletableFuture<ExecutionResult>();
      Mockito.doReturn(result).when(risk).processQuery(Mockitt.anyString(),Mockito.any());

      CompletableFuture<String> method1Result = entry.method1();
      result.complete(someResult);
      assertEquals("some String", method1Result.join());
  }
  ```